# When creating a method without a class in the Rails console, what class is the method under?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Say I did the following while in the `rails console`:

```
def test
  puts "hi"
end
```

I can run `test` and I see hi in the console. What I am trying to understand is where is this `test` method attached to? Is it part of a class? Is there a command I can use to determine where the method belongs to?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this article will throw some light - [Ruby’s Main Object (Top Level Context)](https://codequizzes.wordpress.com/2014/04/23/rubys-main-object-top-level-context/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby creates a object of Object class when you run your console, so all methods are private instance methods of Object class, you can run this to verify.

```
        Object.private_instance_methods.include? :test
```

So when you define your methods in console It is interpreted to this

```
class Object
 def test
  puts "hi"
end
end
```

**More explanation**

I was wanted to explain this but a detailed article is written on this topic,

https://www.sitepoint.com/rubys-top-self-object/